# Delegate trough multiple TableViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

Can anyone help me with this. The last ViewController (*ZoekKaartVC*) is with a Delegate to return a certain value to my first TableViewController (*AddTrip*). So on the press of the save button the views pop trough a custom func loop for getting to the *AddTrip* TableViewController.

Still nothing is returned and the Delegate is not getting called.

I should somewhere put the `ZoekKaartVC.delegate = self` in the *AddTrip* but there are 2 TableViewController's before I reach that initial ViewController so I can not prepare it in my Segue's.

So big story short, how can I make a delegate or something else to return a value from the last *VC* to my first *TableViewController* with 2 *TableViewController's* between.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Please see [Unwind Segues in Swift 5](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/unwind-segues-in-swift-5-e392134c65fd)

Comment: Is `AddTrip` your `rootViewController` of the navigation stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use unwind segue as well if you want to move back to first viewcontroller. Also you can use segue to transfer data as well

```
@IBAction func unwind( _ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to achieve it but currently, I can suggest the minimal way is to fetch the first view controller object and call a method of it.

```
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as [UIViewController];
let addTripVc : AddTrip = viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 4]
addTripVc.eventMethod()
```

Hope it will work.